# How to hide a link depending on the user's role in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roleprovider

I am trying to find out how to hide a link depending on the users role.  So when the user logs in and is sent to the home page, I want the following link (to view users) hidden from view if the user is not an admin:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "User")</li>
```

This is my `Index` in my controller:

```
[Authorize(Users = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var user = db.User.Include(u => u.UserRole);
    return View(user.ToList());
}
```

Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

That is how I usually implement in my view.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "User")</li>
}
```

Comment: Spot On. The other answers complicate the situation by not using built-in abilities.

Comment: And by specifying the role in your View and Controller does not complicate things how? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: Perfect. Sweet and simple!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this still works with the latest MVC framework, but I have used this in the past:

```
public static MvcHtmlString AuthorizedActionLink<TController>
(
    this HtmlHelper helper,
    Expression<Action<TController>> action,
    string linkText, object htmlAttributes
)
where TController : Controller
{
    var routeValuesFromExpression = ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(action);

    return 
        helper.IsAuthorized(action)
            ? helper.RouteLink(linkText, routeValuesFromExpression, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes))
            : null;
}

public static bool IsAuthorized<TController>(this HtmlHelper helper, Expression<Action<TController>> action)
{
    var call = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;

    if (call == null) return false;

    var authorizeAttributes = call.GetAttributes<IAuthorizationFilter>();
    if (authorizeAttributes.Length == 0) return true;

    var controllerContext = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
    var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(typeof(TController));
    var actionDescriptor = new ReflectedActionDescriptor(call.Method, call.Method.Name, controllerDescriptor);

    return authorizeAttributes.All(a => IsAuthorized(a, controllerContext, actionDescriptor));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
    @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin")){           
        <a href="~/Admin/Admin">Admin</a>    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(expression)
{
    code
}
```

in .cshtml file